# Inconsistent day of week formatting

Tags: python, excel, database, date

I am currently working with an excel dataset for work scheduling. I am using python to create a sort of automatic scheduling system. My issue is that the day of the week is inputted by hand, and is often inconsistent. I want to be able to automatically use the excel data to create a schedule for each worker in python.

For example:

- Tgt Hrs: 35, Avail 39; M-Th 8a-4p, Fri 8a-3p;
- Tgt Hrs: 40, Avail 96; M-F and Sunday 12p-12a;
- Tgt Hrs: 30; Avail 43; TuThSun 7:30p-7:30a
- Tgt hrs:30 Avail: 36 W/TH/F: 7p-7a,
- Tgt hrs 40, Avail 96;M/TU/W/F: 7a-11p TH: 12p-11p "on-call" SAT:12p-11p, **What his schedule says Monday is what he goes by, don't add shifts after Monday of each week**
- Tgt Hrs: 40, Avail 45; Avail: M-THU: 8A-5P and Fridays with Client Name ONLY. One client per day no shift shorter then 4hrs. off SAT & SUN
- Tgt Hrs: 15; Avail: 49; Tgt Hrs: 15; Avail: 49; MWF: 9 a.m. to 4 p.m. 
  On-Call on Sunday’s from 1 p.m. to 8 p.m.
- Tgt Hrs; : 40, Avail: 144; Tu-Sat anytime; NO MONDAYS/SUNDAYS

There is no consistent format for the day of the week. On the other hand, my data for the shifts available is very consistent and easy to parse through with:

```
for i in range(len(Date)):

if (Date[i].weekday() == 0):
    WeekDate.append("Monday")

elif (Date[i].weekday() == 1):
    WeekDate.append("Tuesday")

elif (Date[i].weekday() == 2):
    WeekDate.append("Wednesday")

elif (Date[i].weekday() == 3):
    WeekDate.append("Thursday")

elif (Date[i].weekday() == 4):
    WeekDate.append("Friday")

elif (Date[i].weekday() == 5):
    WeekDate.append("Saturday")

elif (Date[i].weekday() == 6):
    WeekDate.append("Sunday")
```

Is there a way that I can parse through the inconsistent data to figure out when everyone can work? I suppose I could create a bunch of different cases for each day of the week, although that may not be as accurate as needed. Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is completely free form, you are never really going to be able to develop a completely accurate system. You can try writing some forms in excel, or use some sort of data validation to restrict acceptable inputs.